# Blazor server side: How to upload files in wwwroot folder

Tags: blazor-server-side

Hi i want to upload files in wwwroot folder when click save button, can you help me?

[Click this Image Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJWux.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are something maybe you didn't.

In the Startup.cs of your project in ConfigureServices method add this:

services.AddScoped<IFileUpload, FileUpload>();

Add this script in your _Host.cshtml in the body:

```
<script src="_content/BlazorInputFile/inputfile.js"></script>
```

You can also use this:

[Uploading File into Project Directory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKzl2THT5zg&ab_channel=ThumbIKR-ProgrammingExamples)